# How do I specify an action on a resource in a namespace in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a resource :products in a namespace :shop, like this:

```
namespace :shop do
  resources :products
  root :to => 'products#index'
end
```

When running `rake routes` it outputs the following:

```
edit_shop_product GET    /shop/products/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"shop/products"}
```

But when I use the `edit_shop_product_path` in a partial view, like this:

```
<%= button_to "Edit", edit_shop_product_path(product) %>
```

I get an ActionController Exception: `No route matches "/shop/products/1/edit"`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer myself in the end. The problem is the `button_to` method which defaults to generating a POST http request. By changing this to a GET like this:

```
<%= button_to "Edit", edit_shop_product_path(product), :method => :get %>
```

Or by using the `link_to` method it works as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a directory named shop under the `controllers/` directory
2. Create a ruby file named `products_controller.rb` under the shop directory
3. Name the controller `class Shop::ProductsController < BaseController`

Comment: All those are in place already. The index, new and create actions work as expected. It's just the edit action that fails with this error when rendering the view.
Thanks for the reply, though!

Comment: That's what I thought too :)= I'll see if I get some more time to debug it this weekend.